# CPP OOP Code review, I cant understand why it doesnt work

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I am new to C++ and making a school project which is a small casino with 2 games, War and BlackJack.
I have card.h, deck.h, player.h, War.h and Game.h classes.

The logic is create a mainDeck inside Game.h which has 52 cards, and than in
War.h split the 52 cards between 2 players.
I have an array of 2 players, when I am running the split cards code, it splits the code but its getting saved in a different deck instead of the player deck, see image:
[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Goo56.png

The split cards code is inside the War constructor:

```
    War::War(Player& p1, Player& p2):Game(p1,p2){
    mainDeck.shuffleDeck();
    int turn = 0;
    Card* temp;
    while (mainDeck.getAmountOfCards() > 0)
    {
        players[turn%2].addCard(*mainDeck.pullCard());
        turn++;
    }
}
void War::playTurn() {
    this->c1 = *players[0].pullCard();
    this->c2 = *players[1].pullCard();
    if (c1.getValue() > c2.getValue())
    {
        players[0].setScore(1);
    }
    else if (c2.getValue() > c1.getValue())
    {
        players[1].setScore(1);
    }
    else
    {
        players[0].setScore(1);
        players[1].setScore(1);
    }
    if (players[0].getDeck()->getAmountOfCards() == 0 || players[1].getDeck()->getAmountOfCards() == 0)
        setIsGameOver(true);
}
```

The Deck header & code:

```
class Deck:public Card
{
private:
    int amountOfCards;
    Card* cards;
public:
    Deck();
    Deck(Card*);
    void setDeck(Card*);
    Card* getDeck();
    void setAmountOfCards(int);
    int getAmountOfCards();
    Card* pullCard();
    void addCard(Card&);
    bool isEmpty();
    bool isFull();
    void shuffleDeck();
};
Deck:: Deck() {
    this->amountOfCards = 0;
    this->cards = new Card[maxSize];
}
Deck::Deck(Card* d) {
    for (int i = 0; i < maxSize; i++)
    {
        this->cards[i] = d[i];
    }
    amountOfCards = 0;
}
```

```
Player header & code:
class Player:public Deck
{
private:
    CString name;
    CString gender;
    int age;
    int id;
    int balance;
    int score;
    Deck* deck;
public:
    Player();
    Player(CString, CString, int, int, int = 0, int = 0);
    int getBalance();
    void setBalance(int);
    CString getName();
    void setName(CString);
    CString getGender();
    void setGender(CString);
    int getAge();
    void setAge(int);
    int getId();
    void setId(int);
    void setScore(int);
    int getScore();
    Deck* getDeck();
    void setDeck(Deck*);
    Card* pullCard();
    Player& operator=(Player&);
};

---------------
Player::Player() {
    this->name = '\0';
    this->gender = '\0';
    this->age = 0;
    this->id = 0;
    this->deck = new Deck();
    this->balance = 0;
    this->score = 0;
}
Player::Player(CString Name, CString Gender, int Age, int Id, int Balance, int Score) {
    this->name = Name;
    this->gender = Gender;
    this->age = Age;
    this->id = Id;
    this->balance = Balance;
    this->deck = new Deck();
    this->score = Score;
}
Deck* Player::getDeck() {
    return this->deck;
}
void Player::setDeck(Deck* d) {
    this->deck = d;
}
Card* Player::pullCard() {
    return this->deck->pullCard();
}
Player& Player::operator=(Player& p) {
    setName(p.getName());
    setBalance(p.getBalance());
    setAge(p.getAge());
    setAmountOfCards(p.getAmountOfCards());
    setDeck(p.getDeck());
    setGender(p.getGender());
    setId(p.getId());
    return *this;
}
```

I cant understand in which Deck the 26 cards are being saved... please help, I bet I used the pointers wrongly..

Comment: There's a lot going on that looks way off, but it's impossible to tell. The Deck ctor looks incomplete, and that's the thing I can say with the most certainty. If a deck is shuffled, handing one to one player and another to another player round-robin style is completely unnecessary in the program. Just split the deck in half.

Comment: I would say, first of all, get rid of those pointers. You dont need it, use stl containers and move sementics, then your error should be revealed (probably at compile time). Try not to duplicate Java OOP.